# How to make hide,show slower

Tags: javascript

How to make hide,show slower ?

This my code:

```
function showHide(what){ 
a=what.getElementsByTagName("div")[0]; 
if(a.style.display=='none'){ 
a.style.display='block'; 
}else{ 
a.style.display='none'; 
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

I thought of writing this, but its very nicely implemented in plain javascript in: http:// jsfiddle.net/gabrieleromanato/cMp7s/

Also jQuery provide fadeIn and fadeOut() functionality if you are open to it.
http://api.jquery.com/fadein/